# Strange texture warping when exporting from C4D to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d-modelling, cinema-4d

I have some troubles when i export 3D model from Cinema4D to OBJ and to Unity. This is in C4D:

---

[image: Photo1]

[image: Photo2]

---

And this is in Unity:

---

[image: Photo1]

[image: Photo2]

---

How can i fix it? Thanks for all answers.

---

Also i have trouble with this:

[image: C4D]

[image: Unity]

Comment: Probably inverted normals on some of the faces?

Comment: @derHugo "Align normals" works with first one. Do you know how to fix second?(I edited and second model's photo was uploaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i just needed to "Align Normals".
Thanks to DerHugo.